# Hibernate: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Not sure why but I am getting following error from my DAO class. It seems to be very straightforward implementation.

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("from MyObject WHERE object_code=:objCode");
query.setParameter("objCode", "ABA");
System.out.println(query.toString());
List<MyObject> result = query.list();
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Enable showsql in config file, that may help you in viewing the query generated and being executed.

Answer (score 1):

The `setParameter` method should be able to infer the right type of your parameter; however you could go for a more specific method like `setString`

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

This assuming that you are sure that `MyObject.object_code` is a string in your underlying database - if not, go for the appropiate setter method as documented here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html